# Use of MDM Vendor Signing CSR for customer

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm, csr

Use of MDM Vendor Signing CSR for customer.

I want to confirm the usage of MDM Vendor Signing CSR for customer.
After the Signed CSR is uploaded to Apple's Notification Portal, customer receives the APNS cert which the customer handovers to the MDM Vendor.

Where is the cert used by MDM Vendor?

Is it used to bundle within Enrollment Profile?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,if you are asking about the APNS certificate downloaded from https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/ which is in .pem format. This apns cert contains the topic which should be used while generating Enroll profile using IPCU.

This detail is provided in [MDM_Protocol](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf) pdf, search for "APSP"